msmtp: account default not found: no configuration file available
I know this is probably a duplicate question but I was not able to solve the problem.
I installed msmtp and msmtp-mta
I created the msmtprc in the /etc folder:
defaults
auth on
tls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile ~/.msmtp.log

# Gmail
account gmail
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
from <username>@gmail.com
user <username>@gmail.com
password <password>
account default : gmail

# Aliases
aliases /etc/aliases

Then I changed the permission with:
sudo chown root:msmtp /etc/msmtprc
sudo chmod 640 /etc/msmtprc

testing with echo "Test email" | msmtp -a default <usermail@domain> I get:
msmtp: account default not found: no configuration file available

Could someone tell me what's wrong with my set-up?
